# How can i dynamically change color of certain words of a paragraph in a Text Widget in flutter

Tags: string, list, flutter, colors, textspan

Suppose you are given two Strings. One contains the words to be colored, and other contains the paragraph. example:

List words =["cow","milk","cattle" ];

String paragraph =
"Cattle, or cows (female) and bulls (male), are large domesticated cloven-hooved herbivores. They are a prominent modern member of the subfamily Bovinae, are the most widespread species of the genus Bos, and are most commonly classified collectively as Bos taurus.";

I need those words in paragraph to be colored or linkable Text. help plz

[Such As like the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt4YF.png)

Comment: you need `RichText` widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [Highlight Text](https://pub.dev/packages/highlight_text).
Here is a small example how you can achieve the effect you desired.

```
Map<String, HighlightedWord> words = {
    "cow": HighlightedWord(
        textStyle: textStyle,
    ),
    "milk": HighlightedWord(
       
        textStyle: textStyle,
    ),
    "cattle": HighlightedWord(
       
        textStyle: textStyle,
    ),
};
```

Your Text

```
TextHighlight(
    text: text, // Your text
    words: words, // Your highlighted words
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split all the words from the paragraph and then dynamically assign Richtext > TextSpan for each word after checking from your list.