# Separate color for a word in sentence which starts with "@"

Tags: flutter, text, textcolor

In flutter how can we add separate color for a word in a sentence which starts with '@' with separate color when displaying that sentence to UI? Like in Instagram when we mention an user in comment section, the tagged user must be in different color

Comment: You want to show different color in text field or listview?

Comment: In a sentence a word which starts with "@" must be in separate color.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use RichText for this case.

Comment: In RichText we are coloring the word which we Knows, here I wants to color the word when I start word with '@" and after that word It must in default color.

Comment: Ok I see, so maybe this question will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252749/how-can-i-dynamically-change-color-of-certain-words-of-a-paragraph-in-a-text-wid

Comment: What I mean was like in Instagram we mention a user in comment section.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).